# Python Sequential Dictionary

Tags: python

How do you create a dictionary (e.g. food_dictionary) with the keys being the unique words in 'word_list' and the value being the list of words immediately following it (i.e. for words that have a word immediately following it)?

```
word_list = [ ['always', 'want', 'pizza' ], ['we', 'want', 'potato', 'chips' ] ]

food_dictionary = { 'always' : ['want'], 'want': ['pizza', 'potato'], 'we': ['want'], potato': ['chips'] }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
from collections import defaultdict

word_list = [ ['always', 'want', 'pizza' ], ['we', 'want', 'potato', 'chips' ] ]

food_dict = defaultdict(list)

for wl in word_list:
    for w1, w2 in zip(wl, wl[1:]):
        food_dict[w1].append(w2)

print food_dict
```

Useful links -
1. [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)
2. [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip)

Answer (score 0):

As always for these types of problems, consider this good ol' zip trick:

```
lst = ['always', 'want', 'want', 'pizza']
pairs = list(zip(lst[:-1], lst[1:])
```

Gives:

```
>>> pairs
[('always', 'want'), ('want', 'want'), ('want', 'pizza')]
```

Next up, we want to group all tuples beginning with the same word:

```
from itertools import groupby

groups = groupby(sorted(pairs, key=lambda x: x[0]), lambda x: x[0])
```

And finally convert to dictionary:

```
dict((k, [x[1] for x in g]) for k, g in groups)
```

---

This can be done for your entire `word_list` in the following manner:

```
from itertools import groupby

word_list = [['always', 'want', 'pizza'], ['we', 'want', 'potato', 'chips']]
pairs = [x for lst in word_list for x in zip(lst[:-1], lst[1:])]
sorted_pairs = sorted(pairs, key=lambda x: x[0])
groups = groupby(sorted_pairs, lambda x: x[0])
food_dict = dict((k, [x[1] for x in g]) for k, g in groups)
```

Gives:

```
>>> food_dict
{'always': ['want'], 'potato': ['chips'], 'want': ['pizza', 'potato'], 'we': ['want']}
```